# Code block "Tidy up" function

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I often come across questions (and sometimes even answers) with poorly formatted code blocks and I was wondering if it would be possible to add a "Tidy up" function/button (like the one on jsFiddle, for example) to the post editing area. This would obviously have to work on selected text only due to the fact that both code and explanations go in the same text area.

I personally think that not only would it help people concentrate on the answers rather than deciphering the question author's code, but it would also make life a lot easier for users who go around editing other people's posts for readability and improvement in general.

I apologize if this has been asked before, I did search for potential duplicates but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Something like [Automatic code reindent button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)? Or [Easy way to either fix up code formatting or educate noobs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50910/easy-way-to-either-fix-up-code-formatting-or-educate-noobs)?

Comment: @Arjan: Indeed. I was thinking about "cleaning" and "tidying" but it never crossed my mind to look for "indenting" ... *facepalm*

Comment: Okay, that means you think they are duplicates? Then we can close this one? (Or even delete it, but then it won't take interested people to the existing posts?) Also nice: [Can we detect unformatted code and give specific help?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74672/can-we-detect-unformatted-code-and-give-specific-help)

Comment: @Arjan: I do think the first question you referenced comes closest to what I had in mind. If the users think this one should be closed, then so be it :)